# Input with wrong size

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6 and I don't know why this is happen. Basically I am using bootstrap grid system, I have mi first div with col-md-12 and then with jQuery I create 4 divs with class col-md-3 with controls inside but when I resize the window the controls jump to other line and leaves a blank space.

[image: Blank spaces when window its resized]

```js
var num = 0;
var lineas = "";
$('#agregar').click(function() {
  agregar();
});

function agregar() {
  num++;

  if (num <= 4) {
    if (num == 1) {
      lineas += '<div class="col-md-3 form-group">';
      lineas += '<label class="control-label hidden-print">Quality:</label">';
      lineas += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden-print" id="aprob' + num + '"/>';
      lineas += '</div>';
      $('#aprobadores').append(lineas);

      lineas = "";
    }
    if (num == 2) {
      lineas += '<div class="col-md-3 form-group">';
      lineas += '<label class="control-label hidden-print">Manufacture:</label">';
      lineas += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden-print" id="aprob' + num + '"/>';
      lineas += '</div>';
      $('#aprobadores').append(lineas);

      lineas = "";
    }
    if (num == 3) {
      lineas += '<div class="col-md-3 form-group">';
      lineas += '<label class="control-label hidden-print">Supp. Produccion:</label">';
      lineas += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden-print" id="aprob' + num + '"/>';
      lineas += '</div>';
      $('#aprobadores').append(lineas);

      lineas = "";
    }
    if (num == 4) {
      lineas += '<div class="col-md-3 form-group">';
      lineas += '<label class="control-label hidden-print">Control de Documentos:</label">';
      lineas += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden-print" id="aprob' + num + '"/>';
      lineas += '</div>';
      $('#aprobadores').append(lineas);

      lineas = "";
    }
  } else {
    $('#agregar').hide();
    $('#lbl1').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-12" id="options">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label id="lbl1" class="control-label hidden-print">Add</label>
    <span class="btn btn-success btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign hidden-print" id="agregar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 hidden-print" id="aprobadores">
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1a5hfj2/)

Comment: share your html code in jsfiddle or here

Comment: Ready, code and fiddle

Comment: You want the labels to appear? Or you just want the inputs stack in a column no matter the width of the browser?

Comment: Labels appear, the problem its the botton of the image, thats a screenshot from my window resize, the top part of the image its the correct form that inputs must appear.

Comment: I add a better image.

Comment: @F.Flores I strongly suggest you look into developer tools such as chrome's inspect element. Running your snippet and inspecting the text-box in question shows you that the text-box was a child of the "Quality" label which is why it had the width it did. From there you know that your label did not close properly and then you know where to start looking for typos and other such simple mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in the HTML strings in the JS. You have `</label">` instead of `</label>`.

```js
var num = 0;
var lineas = "";
$('#agregar').click(function() {
  agregar();
});

function agregar() {
  num++;

  if (num <= 4) {
    if (num == 1) {
      lineas += '<div class="col-md-3 form-group">';
      lineas += '<label class="control-label hidden-print">Quality:</label>';
      lineas += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden-print" id="aprob' + num + '"/>';
      lineas += '</div>';
      $('#aprobadores').append(lineas);

      lineas = "";
    }
    if (num == 2) {
      lineas += '<div class="col-md-3 form-group">';
      lineas += '<label class="control-label hidden-print">Manufacture:</label>';
      lineas += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden-print" id="aprob' + num + '"/>';
      lineas += '</div>';
      $('#aprobadores').append(lineas);

      lineas = "";
    }
    if (num == 3) {
      lineas += '<div class="col-md-3 form-group">';
      lineas += '<label class="control-label hidden-print">Supp. Produccion:</label>';
      lineas += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden-print" id="aprob' + num + '"/>';
      lineas += '</div>';
      $('#aprobadores').append(lineas);

      lineas = "";
    }
    if (num == 4) {
      lineas += '<div class="col-md-3 form-group">';
      lineas += '<label class="control-label hidden-print">Control de Documentos:</label>';
      lineas += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden-print" id="aprob' + num + '"/>';
      lineas += '</div>';
      $('#aprobadores').append(lineas);

      lineas = "";
    }
  } else {
    $('#agregar').hide();
    $('#lbl1').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-12" id="options">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label id="lbl1" class="control-label hidden-print">Add</label>
    <span class="btn btn-success btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign hidden-print" id="agregar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 hidden-print" id="aprobadores">
</div>
```